# Testing abstract class with Moq, without the need of defining fake implementation classes

Tags: c#, moq

I have this abstract class, that I want to test. I want to ensure that when `SomeMethod` is invoked, `ValidateStronglyTypedData` is called.

```
public abstract class SomeAbstractClass<TDataType> where TDataType : class
{
    public ResultType SomeMethod(string someParam)
    {
        TDataType tDataType = convert(someParam);
        this.ValidateStronglyTypedData(tDataType);
    }

    protected abstract ResultType ValidateStronglyTypedData(TDataType stronglyTypedData);
}
```

I've got this:

```
// Arrange
var mockSomeAbstractClass = new Mock<SomeAbstractClass<TestJsonDataType>>();
var testData = "{ 'testProperty': 'test value' }";
mockSomeAbstractClass.Protected().Setup<ValidationResult>("ValidateStronglyTypedData", It.IsAny<TestJsonDataType>());

// Act
mockSomeAbstractClass.Object.ValidateData(testData);

// Assert
mockSomeAbstractClass.Protected().Verify("ValidateStronglyTypedData", Times.Once(), It.IsAny<TestJsonDataType>());
```

but at runtime it complains that it cannot find the method. Is it because the protected method is abstract? It fails on the setup with:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Use ItExpr.IsNull rather than a
>   null argument value, as it prevents proper method lookup.'

I have tried `ItExpr` and still doesn't work. I am guessing it has to do with the class being generic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test abstract classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966439/how-to-unit-test-abstract-classes)

Comment: Why would I create a mock implementation of the abstract class, when I use `Moq`?! That's what the `mockSomeAbstractClass` object is supposed to be.

Comment: Can you include the actual error message?

Comment: As nvoigt said, why not testing the actual implementation instead of testing the abstract class?

Comment: Because I want to directly test the behavior that the abstract defines, without going through the trouble of 'statically' defining a fake implementation. Isn't the `Moq` at runtime a fake implementation?

Comment: You should mock dependencies, not the thing you're testing.

Comment: Oh now that you put it this way, it made sense.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say why bother with all that mocking when you can just do the real thing?

```
public class TestClass
{
    private class DerivedTest : SomeAbstractClass<string>
    {
        public bool WasCalled { get; private set; }

        protected override ResultType ValidateStronglyTypedData(string stronglyTypedData)
        {
            this.WasCalled = true;
        }
    }

    [YourFavoriteFrameWorkAttributeForTestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
         // arrange
         var instance = new DerivedTest();

         // act
         var result = instance.SomeMethod("test");

         // assert
         Assert.IsTrue(instance.WasCalled);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I thought I'd get that 'for free' with `Moq`.

Comment: It seems way more complicated with Moq. Mocking is a tool, to use *when you need it*. Make sure you don't treat everything as a nail, just because you have "hammer" installed. Sometimes, not using every tool in your belt is the easiest way.